# if the system localized

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, harmonic-analysis

Let g be integrable, even function. Let $\Lambda$ be uniformly discrete sequaence (i.e. $\inf|\lambda_i-\lambda_j|>0, \lambda_i, \lambda_j \in \Lambda$).

We say that system $\Psi=\{\psi_n\}$ is $(g, \Lambda)$-localized if $|\psi_n(t)|<cg(t-\lambda_n)$, where $c>0$ some constant.

Let function $f$ be continuous on $R$ with compact support and with exactly one maximum.
We form the followinf system $\{f_{m,k}\}=\left\{f^m\left(t-\frac{k}{2^m}\right)\right\}, k\in Z, m>0.$

I would like to understand if the system $\{f_{m,k}\}$ is  $(g, \Lambda)$-localized?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Re your first sentence, there are no even decreasing functions, and the only even non-increasing functions are constant.

Comment: Certainly not every such system is localized for every $g$ and $\Lambda$. Just look at, say $g=0$. Do you have any more information on the form of solution you're hoping to find?

Comment: Well, I am interested in the case when function $g$ is decreasing function. In particular, when it is a 'hat' function, i.e. something like Gaussian.